# Overriding DataGridViewTextBoxCell and CellPainting

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewtextboxcell

I inherited DataGridViewTextBoxCell because I need to add some custom property to it.

At run-time after creating the DataGridView instance and bind the data I do the following:

```
For k As Integer = 0 To grid.Columns.Count - 1
                grid.Columns(k).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader
                If k > 0 Then grid.Columns(k).CellTemplate = New CustomCell()
Next
```

with the attempt to add to each column different from the first the CustomCell.

The problem is that when I attach to the CellPainting event of the grid and do

```
If e.ColumnIndex < 0 OrElse e.RowIndex <= 0 Then Return

Dim grid As DataGridView = TryCast(sender, DataGridView)
If grid Is Nothing Then Return
If grid.Columns.Count < e.ColumnIndex OrElse grid.Rows.Count < e.RowIndex Then Return

Dim cell As CustomCell = TryCast(grid(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex), CustomCell)
If cell Is Nothing Then Return
```

the **cell** type is never of type **CustomCell** but it remains **DataGridViewTextBoxCell**.

Do you have any idea how can I resolve this issue?

I am working with VS2008 and Framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to add a custom column.  Here is an article I believe may be helpful - [Code Magazine](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0707061&page=1).

Comment: I looked at the article, interesting, but it doesn't solve my problem. I don't want to add a custom column but only cusotmize the DataGridViewTextBoxCell by adding some properties